# python 2.5.1 and supported version of xpath

Tags: python, xpath

trying to figure out how to determine what version of XPath is supported by python 2.4.3/2.5.1 using libxml2dom.

in looking through various docs, i must be missing something!

basically, i'm considering how/if i can have an XPath function, and use regex within the XPath... i understand the XPath v2.0 supports using regex, so i'm hopeful that i can simply do an import libxml2dom, and have the ability to then incorporate regex in the XPath functions..

thanks

Answer (score 1):

I believe that Python is loading whichever version of [`libxml2`](http://www.xmlsoft.org/) is on your machine.  I think that all versions of `libxml2` implement XPath 1.0.  I don't know of any Python ready implementation of XPath 2.0.